# Laravels GroupBy query is not selecting top record from each group

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, group-by

I have a database with multiple records, that looks like this:

```
Id  | user_id | city          | users_language  | updated_at         |
_____________________________________________________________________
383 | 13      | New York      | PHP             | 2015-01-10 05:06:58
382 | 13      | New York      | JAVA            | 2015-01-10 04:06:58
381 | 13      | New York      | RUBY            | 2015-01-10 03:06:58
380 | 15      | Boston        | JavaScript      | 2015-01-10 02:06:58
379 | 14      | San Francisco | C++             | 2015-01-10 01:06:58
```

I am trying to get LAST recorded data that are updated in last 10 minutes and then group them by user_id. Query that I am using is:

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('-10 minutes');
$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$activeusers = DB::table('active_user_data')->where('updated_at','>=',$formatted_date)
->select(DB::raw('*,max(id) as id'))
->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
->groupby('user_id')
->get();
```

But database record that query is getting for user with id 13 is following:

```
383 | 13 | New York | RUBY | 2015-01-10 03:06:58
```

I want to get latest updated record for each data column sot that not only MAX ID is correct, but all the columns **for each group contains data with latest ID value.**

```
383 | 13 | New York | PHP | 2015-01-10 05:06:58
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In raw Mysql query you need a self join to get the latest row for each user_id

```
select a.*
from active_user_data a
join (select max(id) id ,user_id
      from active_user_data
     group by user_id) b
on(a.id = b.id and a.user_id = b.user_id)
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb3aa/1)

Using Laravel's querybuilder i guess this one will do the job

```
DB::table('active_user_data as a')
    ->select(DB::raw('a.*'))
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT max(id) id ,user_id FROM active_user_data  GROUP BY user_id ) AS b'), function($join)
    {
        $join->on('a.id', '=', 'b.id');
        $join->on('a.user_id', '=', 'b.user_id ');
    })->get();
```